# CakePHP : How to access nested associated field?

Tags: php, database, cakephp, eager-loading

I'm new to CakePHP.

I have a problem when getting nested field. I am not sure
if other people have encountered the same problem before.

Say, I have three tables with the following filds:

1. User

   - id
   - username
   - password
   - registration_ip
2. Post

   - id
   - user_id
   - title
   - body
   - posting_ip
3. Comments

   - id
   - user_id
   - post_id
   - body
   - commenting_ip

I want to make the following query:

```php
<?php
    ... 
    $query = $this->getTableLocator()->get("users")->find();
    $query->contain([
        "Posts",        // --> retrieve posts made by a user
        "Comments",     // --> retrieve comments made by a user

        // --> retrieve comments made to a post of a user
        "Posts.Comments" => function ($q) {
            /**
             * Here lies the problem. This is just one example, there
             * might be other examples for this. 
             *
             * I want to select comments to a user's post which IP is 
             * the same as the user's registration IP. 
             * 
             * But when I do, it creates an errors. 
             *  
             * How can multiple dots (nested associations) work in
             * CakePHP?
             * 
             * In Laravel, if I remember correctly, 
             * I was able to do something similar to this. 
             * 
             * I want to use dots to refer to nested associations. 
             * (more than one level).
             */
            return $q->where([
                "Posts.Comments.commenting_ip" => "Users.registration_ip"
            ]);
        }
    ]);
```

Is it possible to use these chained dots to refer to deeper associations.

A possible solution I have in mind is to create another association
in the UsersTable (say CommentsToPosts). This might break the nesting
of Posts and Comments though.

Is there a straightforward solution without having to create another
association?

Thanks a lot! Hope this question may also be relevant to other people's question in the future.

Comment: Even though problems might be obvious for people that are familiar with CakePHP, when receiving errors, please always include the exact error message and the related stacktrace (both can be found in the log files) - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing nested associations using the dot syntax is not meant to be used in conditions, you'd simply use the target association alias there, as the passed query will always be the one that includes the associated table.

Furthermore, if you want to compare fields in key/value conditions, then you need to use expressions, for example an identifier expression, as otherwise the value side of such conditions ends up as a bound parameter.

After reading your comments I realized that you didn't make `Users` accessible, which is required as `hasMany` and `belongsToMany` are retrieved in separate queries, as you've noticed. You can achieve this by including the `belongsTo` association from `Comments` to `Users` too (if it doesn't exist, create it), that should join it into the query that retrieves the comments.

```php
$query->contain([
    'Posts.Comments' => [
        'queryBuilder' => function (\Cake\ORM\Query $q) {
            return $q->where([
                'Comments.commenting_ip' => $q->identifier('Users.registration_ip');
            ]);
        },
        'Users',
    ],
]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Passing Conditions to Contain](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations-via-contain)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using Identifiers in Expressions](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-identifiers-in-expressions)**

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the info. and clarification.

P.S. Is it possible to disambiguate between "Post.Comments" (posts made to a comment of a user) and "Comments" (comments of a user)?

Comment: @LJS.A. You'd have to be more specific as to where exactly and how exactly you need to disambiguate things.

Comment: I tried your code with the `$q->identifier(...)`. 
`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Users.registration_ip' in 'where clause'.` Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The debugger shows this as the SQL query. `SELECT Comments.id AS Comments__id, Comments.user_id AS Comments__user_id, Comments.post_id AS Comments__post_id, Comments.body AS Comments__body, Comments.commenting_ip AS Comments__commenting_ip, Comments.created_at AS Comments__created_at, Comments.updated_at AS Comments__updated_at FROM comments Comments WHERE (Comments.post_id in (:c0,:c1) AND Comments.commenting_ip = Users.registration_ip)`

Mmmm... Does CakePHP execute eager loading as separate queries from the look of it? How can we refer to parents then?

Comment: @LJS.A. It does so for `hasMany` and `belongsToMany` associations, yes. I didn't really look at what type of associations you probably have set up with what configuration, I just assumed that you've made `Users` accessible - sorry! You can fix this by throwing in the `Users` association too, see my edited answer.